# How to Split Chinese Character?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to split this kind of Chinese character?

```
a = ['马来西亚', '是一个多元国家']
```

which display result like/similar like this:

```
马
来
西
亚
，
是
一
个
多
元
国
家
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looping explicity, I prefer using built-in methods:

```
print('\n'.join(list(','.join(a))))
```

The following steps are performed:

- `list.join` method joins all sentences delimited by a comma `,`
- `list()` converts the join result to a list with each character being a single list element
- `'\n'.join()` joins each character in the list separated by a line break

Major advantage of this over explicit looping:

- more pythonic ;)
- much faster for large sentences
- less code, more readability

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
a = ['马来西亚', '是一个多元国家']
for idx, i in enumerate(a):
    print(*i, sep='\n')
    if idx!=len(a)-1:
        print(",")
```

---

```
马
来
西
亚
,
是
一
个
多
元
国
家
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use nested loop.

```
a = ['马来西亚', '是一个多元国家']
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        print(j)
    print('\t')
```

Comment: is there is any way that it have , or space between 2 sentence when print out the result?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
i = 0
for item in a:
    for char in item:
        print(char)
    if not i == len(a) - 1: print(',')
i += 1
```